# Logging function call in x64dbg without asm

Tags: x64dbg, trace

I want to log every call of the function to see the what parameters are passed and function result. Currently I'm loading a DLL module, hook function I need and then see function output in my log file.

I've already found an answer below how to log every call but my asm knowledge is not enough to write my own Log templates.
[Record all calls to specific function? Olly/x64dbg](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17271/record-all-calls-to-specific-function-olly-x64dbg)

Is there a plugin for x64dbg which does that automatically or makes things easies for my purpose?